# Use Ajax and validate a form within the same <script>

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to validate & use ajax within the same `<script>` tag, is this the correct way to do it? The ajax isn't working.

The console gives the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`  . I don't understand, it looks defined to me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('#formsubmit').validate({
            rules:  {

            numberofwelds: "required",
            numberofconwelds: "required"
                    },

            messages: {
            numberofwelds: "Please enter the number of welds",
            numberofconwelds: "Please enter number of con"
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
            }           }) 





$(".ajax-link").click( function() {
            var data = {
                action: 'test_response',
                            post_var: 'this will be echoed back'
            };
            $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert(response);
            });
            return false;
        });

            });
```

Comment: "Is it possible to do this within the same script tag?" Ya, sure it is possible. "The ajax isn't working" What does mean? Is click event fired at least? Any script error server side?

Comment: `"The ajax isn't working, but I haven't got an error."` - Then what *do* you have?  What indication do you have that "the AJAX isn't working"?  When you debug this, is that line of code reached?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Is the request sent to the server?  What is the server's response?  "It isn't working" isn't a valid problem description.

Comment: This error means you are not including jQuery correctly or calling it before including it

Comment: Sorry. I'm very new to coding in general. The Javascript console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined `  It looks defined to me?

Comment: @mattnewbie post code you are using to include jQuery. Jquery is a javascript librarie which needs to be included on page in order to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in order to use it. For example, using goggle CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can put it in HEAD section, even usually not the best way to include any script.

If you are using chrome and not running a server, you have to specify protocol otherwise `file://`
 would be assumed. So instead use:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm already calling Jquery, perhaps just a little bit late. Have added an update. Thank-you.

Comment: I'm afraid, i try to stay far away from WP, cannot help you on this one :(